# Suppose A and B are sets, finite or infinite. Prove relationship of cardinality and power set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Question:** Suppose A and B are sets, finite or infinite. Prove: If $|A| \le |B|$ then $|P(A)| \le |P(B)|$ where $P$ denotes a power set and $|A|$ denotes the cardinality of $A$.

**Approach:** Since $|A| \le |B|$, there exists an injection $f:A \to B$. We can use this to construct an injection $F:P(A) \to P(B)$.

Define $F(X)$ as follows, $F(X)=\{t \in T| t=f(s) \text{ for some } s \in X\}$.

This is clearly a function from $P(A)$ to $P(B)$, It remains to show that it is injective.

**Injective**

Suppose there were two sets $X,Y \subseteq T$, $X \not=Y$ and $F(X)=F(Y)$. Consider an $s$ that is in one of these sets and not the other. Then there must be another element $s'$ in $Y$ such that $f(s)=f(s')$, since otherwise $f(s)$ would not be in $F(Y)$. But, $f$ was a injection, so this cannot be the case.

Does my answer look good? Please give me some advice! Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, this is correct.